# Show a message when an image won't load in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, images

Currently in chat if an image (and I assume video) cannot be loaded on the client side we're left with a big empty box.

[![Chat example][1]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/119826#119826)

Please display a warning message instead.  This is both for clarity and for mod purposes (I can't moderate what I can't see).

Something like "Could not load [http://images.com/bunnies.jpg"](http://images.com/bunnies.jpg%22) Would be most helpful.

Comment: I'm very disappointed that I can't see that bunnies pic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll see whether we can do something fun here...

Comment: @CRoss _what have you done?!_

Comment: @Popular Demand Apparently something _Awesome_!

Comment: Apparently I'm confused about how chat works, or they're really going to take the time to detect client-side if the browser is blocked from loading an image

Comment: @Michael Mrozek They do every other bloody thing client side.  Why not?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is even possible (maybe with Javascript); it's your browser that's failing to load the image, not the server. Your browser should handle displaying a broken image indicator if it couldn't load properly; I see:

[image: Screenshot of broken image on chat]

---

**Edit**: Never mind:

[image: Screenshot of implemented feature]